# Live update projects photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, posters

I am working on some posters, I like to see how the poster will look in a frame. I have another project open that I can paste the work into. Is there any way to make the poster live update in the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PSD file with your frame: Click File > Place linked
Find your artwork PSD file and place it as you like.

You can double click the layer thumbnail for you artwork to open it, or just open the file as usual.

It updates every time you save the artwork.

Comment: awesome! worked first time thankyou! is there any way to make it more "live" or do i have to save each time?

Comment: You have to save it each time, just like in Illustrator or InDesign.